# Estimation of change in enthalpy of a gas phase reaction using bond enthalpies

Tags: bond, enthalpy

Estimate ∆H for the following gas phase reaction: 
$$\ce{C2H4 + 3 O2 ⟶ 2 CO2 + 2H2O}$$

I have been having trouble on this problem for a long time, and I was hoping someone would help me with it. I tried using the average bond enthalpies, but that always got me the wrong answer. Below is a table of average bond enthalpies in kJ/mol.

[image]

Comment: Hi Smith!  welcome to Chem.SE! We require you to show your efforts on this problem. What formulae/steps did you try? Please add this to your question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi John, you said that "I tried using the average bond enthalpies, but that always got me the wrong answer." Do note that telling us what 
exactly you did with the bond enthalpies will help us help you much better. Thanks!

Comment: How do you know the result is wrong and not just _imprecise_? See, the word "estimate" (rather than "calculate") is there for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Hess' Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hess%27s_law):  $\Delta$H = $\Sigma$ Enthalpy of Bonds Broken - $\Sigma$ Enthalpy of Bonds Formed

**Reactants**

- Bond enthalpy of C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>4</sub> = 602 + (413 * 4) = 2254 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>
- Bond enthalpy of O<sub>2</sub> = 3 * 498 = 1494 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>
- $\therefore$ $\Sigma$ Enthalpy of Bonds Broken= 2254 + 1494 = 3748 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>

**Products**

- Bond enthalpy of CO<sub>2</sub> = (799 * 2) * 2 = 3196 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>
- Bond enthalpy of H<sub>2</sub>O = (463 * 2) * 2 = 1852 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>
- $\therefore \Sigma$ Enthalpy of Bonds Formed = 3196 + 1852 = 5048 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>

**Overall**

- $\Delta$H = 3748 - 5048 = -1300 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>

---

After having a quick Google search for the enthalpy change of combustion for ethene, it came up as -1411 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>. Our calculated answer isn't far off. I'm hoping we got the same answer.